# Инициализация библиотеки при загрузке приложения

Tags: c#, wpf, dll

Добавляю в решение библиотеку пользовательских элементов управления WPF.
Хочу добавить `c#` файл с кодом в эту библиотеку, что-бы он выполнялся при подключении к приложению автоматически. Типа `Initialization`. Как реализовать?

Comment: Что значить _c# файл с кодом_? Вы хотите кинуть `.cs` файл в приложение, чтобы он там сбилдился и автоматически проинициализировался?

Comment: Вот тут http://www.vr-online.ru/content/c-plagin-za-5-sekund-3890 написано про самый простой способ реализации плагинов, можно в эту сторону копнуть, хотя немного не понятно что конкретно вам нужно.

Comment: В библиотеку так просто файл не "добавить". Вообще можно создать событие, возникающее при подключении библиотеки, но тогда придётся библиотеку подключать в рантайме, что, я думаю, не очень удобно.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нет, такой функциональности в .NET нету. Простое подключение библиотеки не вызывает никакого кода этой библиотеки, код должен быть вызван основным приложением. (Иначе приходилось бы загружать библиотеку полностью в самом начале работы приложения, а библиотеки грузятся *лениво*, только при первом обращении к ним — и поверьте, вы не хотите это менять.)

Вам придётся организовывать нужную функциональность вручную, и главному приложению придётся сотрудничать.

---

Возможно, вам стоит посмотреть в сторону [MEF](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/mef/index). Это довольно тяжёлый фреймворк, но он представляет нужную вам функциональность почти из коробки.